# Two norm optimization with unit norm constraint

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I am stuck with the following problem. Could someone give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Problem setting:
Let $X\in R^{N\times k}$ and $\theta\in R^k$. Now we consider $\hat{\theta} = \arg\min \|X\theta\|^2_2$ with constraint of $\|\theta\|_2=1$. Please solve $\hat{\theta}$.

I have considered the problem as $\hat{\theta} = \arg\min \theta'X'X\theta$ with constraint of $\theta'I \theta = 1$, where we have $I\in R^{k\times k}$.

Now by taking derivative of $\theta'X'X\theta$, we have $2 X'X\theta = 0$ and $\theta'I \theta = 1$. It seems to be a contradiction. Is there any hints for solving the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't just take the derivative of an objective function in a constrained case like this; you have to employ a Lagrangian method, for instance. Though in this *particular* case, the result follows from the basic definition of singular values. Is that an acceptable way to solve this, or are they asking you to take a particular approach?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks for reply. If we consider the Lagrangian method, it is still weird. Specifically, we have $L=\theta'X'X\theta + \lambda(\theta'\theta-1)$. By taking the derivative of $L$ with respect to $\theta$, we have $2X'X\theta + 2\lambda\theta = 0$. There is no solution for $\theta$?! There is no constraint on the approach for solving the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are myriad solutions to that equation. Any $\theta$ in the null space of $X^TX+\lambda I$ will do.

Comment: Well, I mean that there is no unique closed-form solution for $\theta$. It seems that the problem setting is problematic if we finally want to have a closed form solution.

Comment: Closed form solutions are overrated. The answer here is that theta is the right singular vector associated with the minimum singular value.